# I try to program cm to inch/foot - inch to cm,meter

Tags: java

When i try to compile it, i got an error ";" in line

```
double cm1 (inch_to_cm*2.54);
```

It must be in same windows: cm to inch/foot inch to cm/meter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Centimer_Inch
{

public static void main (String[] args)
{
        // 2.54cm is 1 inch
       Scanner cm = new Scanner(System.in); //Get INPUT from pc-Keyboard
       System.out.println("Enter The Centimeters:"); // Write input
       double centimeters = cm.nextDouble(); // STAM מקבל את הסנטימטר
       double inches = Math.round( (centimeters / 2.54) * 100 ) / 100.0; // STAM לוקח את הסנטימטר ומחלק ב2.54
       System.out.println(inches +"Inches");

       double foot=Math.round( (inches/12) *100) / 100.0;
       System.out.print(foot +"Foots");

       // inch to cm
       Scanner inch1 = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter The Inch");
       double inch_to_cm = inch1.nextDouble();

       double cm1 (inch_to_cm*2.54); //From INCH TO CM
       System.out.println(inch_to_cm);

    }
}
```

Comment: and how can i do Space between the input CM TO INCH\FOOT
Between  Inch to cm

Comment: See the answer I gave here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13211447/57695

Answer (score 0):

You missed the equal sign:

```
double cm1 = (inch_to_cm * 2.54); //From INCH TO CM
```

When you want help about an error message from the compiler, tell what the error message is (and try to understand it before posting the question).

Answer (score 0):

```
double cm1 (inch_to_cm*2.54); //From INCH TO CM
```

Should be:

```
double cm1 = (inch_to_cm*2.54); //From INCH TO CM
```

You need to assign results of computation to cm1. `=` is assignment operator in java (I hope you know this because you did same in other places)

Answer (score 0):

you are not assigning the value to your double variable.
you are missing an `=` sign, thus compiler error

```
double cm1 (inch_to_cm*2.54);
```

should be

```
double cm1 =(inch_to_cm*2.54);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also at the end where it says

```
System.out.println(inch_to_cm);
```

it should be

```
System.out.println(cm1);
```

to be converted back to centimeters.